# iptables-restore: line 1 failed message

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-10.04

I am trying to change iptables to the following

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             127.0.0.0/8         reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:www 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:30000 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            icmp echo-request 
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere            limit: avg 5/min burst 5 LOG level debug prefix `iptables denied: ' 
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

When I run the /sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.up.rules command, I get the following message:

iptables-restore: line 1 failed

Can anyone give me any advice on what to do? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've posted is the output of `iptables -L`, and is NOT a valid format for iptables.  What you'll want to do is use `iptables-save` to get a copy of a correctly formatted ruleset.

Comment: Thank you. I figured out that they have to be posted in a different format.

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us what is at line 1 of /etc/iptables.up.rules? It seems that this file was overwritten to a format that wasn't from /sbin/iptables-save.

The other option is that you you need to use sudo to execute the restore command.